# How to split a line with priority regex/pattern matching, Java

Tags: java, regex

So I know this question has probably been asked a bunch of times before, but I'm essentially trying to do the same thing as the JVM when it looks at run arguments on the command line, e.g.:

```
java MyProgram arg1 arg2 "argument three" arg4
```

The priority match is if the argument is in quotes, treat it as one argument; otherwise, separate them by spaces.

I'm reading through a CSV file, but sometimes one section is contained in quotes, so it might look something like this:

```
value, value, value, value, "value, value", value
```

Thus it adds one more element to the returned array from `String.split().`

The regex I'm trying to use:

```
String[] data = line.split("(\".*\")|,", -1);
```

So essentially I'm trying to say, if there's a double quote followed by anything, followed by another quote, treat that as priority (left - right); otherwise, split it based on the comma.

That regex doesn't seem to be working though, because I still get one more value on that line than there are fields (headers) in the file.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not the best with regex. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried out `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: This is a common problem without a simple code solution. Isn't using an external library an option? I saw a couple on google, but have never used any myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following (matches strings using delimiters as space and comma and ignores delimiters inside quotes..same problem different approach):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s,\\\"']+|\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"|'([^']*)'");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

**Edit:** You can use `[^\\s,\\\"]+|\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"` for allowing only double quotes (as suggested by uraimo).

**Output:**

```
[value, value, value, value, "value, value", value]
```

Comment: That could be reduced to `[^\\s,\\\"]+|\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"` to strictly allow only what he asked (doesn't consider single quote).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for either:

- the start of the string or a comma `(?:^|,)` followed by zero-or-more whitespaces `\s*` followed by a quote `"` then any number of non-quote characters `([^"]*)` then another quote `"` then zero-or-more whitespace `\s*` and either a trailing comma or the end-of-line `(?=,|$)` - which when combined gives `(?:^|,)\s*"([^"]*)"\s*(?=,|$)` or
- the start of the string or a comma `(?:^|,)` followed by zero-or-more non-comma characters `([^,]*)` and either a trailing comma or the end-of-line `(?=,|$)` which when combined gives `(?:^|,)([^,]*)(?=,|$)`

Putting the two together you get the regular expression:

```
(?:^|,)(?:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*|([^,]*))(?=,|$)
```

And you can implement it like this:

```
String test = "value, value, value, value, \"value, value\", value";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(?:^|,)(?:\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*|([^,]*))(?=,|$)" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( test );
while( matcher.find() ){
    String value = matcher.group(1);
    if ( value == null )
        value = matcher.group(2).trim();
    System.out.println( value );
}
```

If you want to expand it to allowing escaped quotes in the quoted string then you want:

```
(?:^|,)(?:\s*"((?:[^"]|\\")*)"\s*|([^,]*))(?=,|$)
```

Which can be written, in Java, as:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(?:^|,)(?:\\s*\"((?:[^\"]|\\\\\")*)\"\\s*|([^,]*))(?=,|$)" );
```